# Pointer Problems in LinkedList C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list, traversal

So, I tried porting my java version of a linked list to c++, and I am having great difficulty using pointers to point to the correct objects. The goal of the remove traverse and reverse traverse is to simply print out the values of the linked list in order and then reverse order. Here is the code. The reason I post most of it rather than certain sections is because I believe you'll need the context of it.

The console outputs:
They are equal
removed 5
traverse
-858993460

It prints out they are equal because it breaks immediately on the first iteration of the while loop in remove(data).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Node{

public:
    int data;
    Node *pNext;


    Node();
    Node(int x);
};

Node::Node(){
    data = NULL;
    pNext = NULL;
}

Node::Node(int x){
    data = x;
    pNext = NULL;
}

class List{

private: 
    Node *head = NULL;
public:

    void insert(int data){

        Node temp(data);
        temp.pNext = head;

        head = &temp;



    }

    Node removeHead(){
        if (head != NULL){
            Node *temp = head;
            head = head->pNext;

            return *temp;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Empty List" << endl;
        }
        return NULL;
    }


    Node remove(int data){

        Node *previousLink = head;
        Node *currentLink = head;

        while (currentLink->data != data){
            if (currentLink == currentLink->pNext){
                cout << "They are equal" << endl;
                break;
            }

            previousLink = currentLink;
            if (currentLink->data == NULL)
            currentLink = currentLink->pNext;

            cout << "Current " << currentLink->data << " Previous " 
            << previousLink->data <<endl;

        }

        if (head->data == data){
            head = head->pNext;
        }
        else{
            previousLink->pNext = currentLink->pNext;
        }

        return *currentLink;
    }

    void traverse(){

        traverse(head);
    }

    void reverseTraverse(){
        reverseTraverse(head);
    }


private:
    void traverse(Node *link){
        cout << link->data << endl;

        if (link != link->pNext)
            traverse(link->pNext);
    }

    void reverseTraverse(Node *link){
        if (link != link->pNext)
            traverse(link->pNext);

        cout << link->data << endl;
    }



};

int main(){
    cout << " Hello World\n";
    List list;


    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
        list.insert(i);

    list.remove(5);
    cout << "removed 5\n";

    cout << "traverse" << endl;
    list.traverse();

    cout << "reverse" << endl;
    list.reverseTraverse();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Its not really clear to me why you don't use a built-in STL container. Perhaps it would be easier to use [Standard Containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), like a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if you say:

```
Node temp(data);
```

then it's only a local variable and it'll disappear after the enclosing function ends, e.g. your insert function. Use new instead, then delete it when it gets removed.

BTW, you don't need the List class. The Node IS the list.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I thought pointers would still work even if it wasn't allocated. Haven't used C++ in a longggg time. Thanks for your help! This fixed it.